# How to retain my nsstring when popping to another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsstring

I am trying make an NSString retain its value in another view controller, and it works when I push to the viewcontroller controller. However when I use the apple's navigation back button (automatically generated) it doesn't retain the value. How do I overcome this?  I believe the automatic back button is poptoviewcontroller. I will post some code to help give you an idea.

```
NSString *ee = @"energy";
optViewController.energy = ee;
```

Controller I am trying to  goto.

```
 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *energy
```

Comment: The view controller will get released if you don't keep a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this answer and it worked great: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/2670912.  I found that using a protocol worked the best for me. And it helped me avoid rigidity.